# Printing a triangle in r

Tags: r, visualization, shapes

I'm trying to write some code to give me an output that looks like:

```
              *
             * *
            * * *
           * * * *
          * * * * *
           * * * *
            * * *
             * *
              *
```

Given my limited r experience the closest I got was:

```
for(i in 1:5) {
  print(strrep("*", i))
}

for(i in 4:1) {
  print(strrep("*", i))
}
```

which gives me:

```
# *
# **
# ***
# ****
# *****

and

# ****
# ***
# **
# *
```

Any guidance would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `for(i in c(1:5, 4:1)) cat(strrep("*", i), "\n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pad extra space

```
for(i in c(1:5, 4:1))
  cat( paste0(strrep(" ", 5 - i), strrep("* ", i), "\n") )
```

---

```
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
  * * * 
   * * 
    *
```

Comment: `for(i in c(1:5, 4:1)) cat(strrep(" ", 5 -i), strrep("* ", i), "\n")` will do too.